# No SVN_REVISION in jenkins environment variable

Tags: svn, jenkins, revision

using jenkins 2.46.1 and Subversion plugin 2.7.2
when doing a checkout fron SVN server - there is not SVN_REVISION environment variable created.
The only thing I have is SvnServerURLand SvnUsername

How can I get the SVN_REVISION number as environment variable or alternatively a simple solution to retrieve it in jenkins as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command in add build step as Shell or batch command

```
echo %SVN_REVISION%
```

It will display the head svn revison number.

Comment: Or use ${SVN_REVISION} on a Linux machine.

Answer (score -4):

Revision number of a specific file or directory path can be accessed using this command in command prompt on windows:

```
svn info --show-item last-changed-revision <put_your_svn_URL_here>
```

NOTE: this works with svn client CollabNetSubversion version 1.9 or higher